# Analysing a multi-threaded Java application

Tags: java, multithreading

In an open source application I'm participating, we've got a bug, where the application doesn't always close properly. That's what I'd like to solve.

Experience has shown that this happens most of the time when threads and processes are being started, but not managed correctly (e.g. a thread is waiting on a socket connection, the application is being shut down and the thread keeps on waiting).
With this in mind I've searched for '.start()' in the entire source and found 53 occurrences (which scared me a bit).
As a first step, I wanted to create a helper class (ThreadExecutor) where the current code 'thread.start()' would be replaced by 'ThreadExecutor.Execute(thread)' to have a) only a few changes in the existing source and b) a single class where I can easily check which threads don't end as they should. To do this I wanted to

- add the thread to be executed to a list called activeThreads when calling the Execute method
- start the thread
- remove it from the activeThreads list when it ends.

This way I'd have an up to date list of all executing threads and when the app hangs on shutdown I could see in there which thread(s) is(are) causing it.

Questions:

- What do you think about the concept? I'm usually coding c# and know how I'd do it using .NET with workers, but am not too sure what's best in Java (I'd like to modify as few lines of code as possible in the existing source).
- If the concept seems ok, how can I get notified of a thread terminating. I'd like to avoid having an additional thread checking every once in a while what the state of all threads contained in activeThreads is, to remove them if they terminated.

Just to clarify: Before figuring out how to terminate the application properly, what I'm asking here is what's the best/easiest way to find which threads are at cause for certain test cases which are pretty hard to reproduce.

Comment: If you make the threads daemon - won't they be killed when the application is killed?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29

Comment: Have you tried taking a thread dump when the app doesn't shut down properly to seen what threads are stuck and what they're doing?  That might give you a few clues.  More info: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/Stacktrace/

Comment: Nope, haven't made a thread dump yet. I'll check out both suggestions. Usually I prefer managing the lifecycle of threads myself instead of killing everything regardless of the thread state. It makes me feel more in control :)

Comment: Well finding out which threads are misbehaving is the first way to fix it and a thread dump will give all the necessary clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make all threads daemon(when all remaining threads are daemon the `JVM` terminates). Use [thread.setDaemon(true)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29) before starting each thread.

Comment: This sounds like the equivalent of shooting your application in the face so it'll die for sure.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what the OP wants? There is some process in a thread continuously listening somewhere. The application is closed and the process automatically terminates.

Comment: Let me put it this way: The OP says there's a bug where the application doesn't terminate properly.  My guess is that the bug isn't that not all of the threads are daemon threads.  There likely threads that are blocked that prevent the application from coming down.  These threads presumably have some important work to do, and making them daemon threads just so the application will terminate probably isn't going to solve the problem.

Comment: @Paul Morie: but why such a guess?  I've seen more than once Java applications not exiting because it's all too easy to forget to *setDaemon(true)* on non-important threads.  As long as you keep control of at least one non-daemon thread and, paraphrasing you, don't *"shoot that one thread in the face"*, you're not *"shooting your application in the face"* [sic].   As Petar Minchev pointed out: it's basically the whole idea behind daemon threads.  Now if the OP's threads should be daemon ones or not, that I have no idea... But I still find Petar's point a valid one.

Comment: This might be a simple solution, not the one I prefer though. Have to check how the processes (e.g. transcoding of a video using mencoder) behaves with this

Comment: @User988052: It certainly may be that there's a thread that should have been a daemon thread that wasn't.  My point is that it bears some investigation before taking action, that's all.

Comment: @Petar: see above.  My first comment was too snarky.  Apologies.

Comment: When the application closes down (btw I could have mentioned this is being done using a shutdown hook) I'm allowed to kill everything (no persistence to guarantee or similar things). As I've commented above, I prefer to know what's going on and be able to end threads/processes properly instead of killing everything.

Comment: @Philippe - if you have no requirement to persist, commit or otherwise complete stuff on app close, why inflict any more work on yourself than you have to?  Haven't you got enough other bugs to fix, (if not, I have plenty you can have:)? The OS is very, very good at stopping threads, much better than you or I am. If you can, let it do its job.

Comment: @Martin James - Very valid remark! Thanks for your offer but we've indeed got enough other bugs to sort ;) On one side I'm used to fully manage the life-cycle of threads in the apps I'm writing (usually it is required) and additionally it's an exercise, where I'm wondering why all these threads are required. I'll definitely check the behaviour when setting setDaemon(true), currently none of the threads are.

Answer (score 6):

I would attempt to analyze your application's behavior before changing any code.  Code changes can introduce new problems - not what you want to do if you're trying to solve problems.

The easiest way to introspect the state of your application with regard to which threads are currently running is to obtain a thread dump.  You said that your problem is that the application hangs on shutdown.  This is the perfect scenario to apply a thread dump.  You'll be able to see which threads are blocked.

You can read more about thread dumps [here](http://java.sys-con.com/node/1611555).

Answer (score 2):

You could try to look into your application using `jvisualvm` (which is shipped with the jdk, find it in the bin folder of your jdk). JVisualVM can connect to your application and display a lot of interesting information, including which processes are still running. I'd give that a shot before starting down the road you describe.

Here is some [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html) on JVisualVM should you need it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way in java is to use [Thread pools](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) instead of Threads directly (although using threads directly is accepted). Thread pools accept `Runnable` objects, which you can see as Tasks. The idea is that most threads would do a small task and then end, because making a `Thread` is expensive and harder to manager you can use the threadpool, which allows things like 'ThreadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination()`. If you have more tasks than Threads in the pool, remaining tasks will just be queued.

Changing a `Thread` into a `Runnable` is easy, and you can even execute a runnable on a Thread you make yourself.

Note that this might not work for threads that run a long time, but your question seems to suggest that they will eventually finish.

As for your second question, the best way to find out which threads are running at a certain point is to run the application in a debugger (such as Eclipse) and pause all threads on a breakpoint in the close function.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the trial edition of jprofiler or something similar, which gives you a lot of insight into what your application and its threads actually do.

Don't change the code yet, but try to reproduce and understand when this happens.

Answer (score 1):

Create yourself a static thread pool.

```
static ExecutorService threads = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
```

For every start of thread change:

```
new Thread(new AThread()).start();
```

to

```
threads.submit(new AThread ());
```

When your code exits, list all running threads with:

```
List<Runnable> runningThreads = threads.shutdownNow();
for ( Runnable t : runningThreads ) {
  System.out.println("Thread running at shutdown: "+t.toString());
}
```

This will not only shut down all running threads, it will list them out for you to see what their issue is.

**EDIT**: Added

If you want to keep track of all running threads use:

```
Future f = threads.submit(new AThread ());
```

and store it in a list somewhere. You can then find out about its state with calls like:

```
f.isDone();
... etc.
```

Comment: cached thread pools aka one of the most horrible inventions ever made.. Better REALLY make sure that you understand what you're doing there.

Comment: Agreed Voo, but OP wanted something unobtrusive and this is very simple to use as a replacement for uncontrolled thread use. I would strongly suggest, once the issue is resolved, that they use one or more `FixedThreadPool`s.